# access specific value from file loaded with file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have problems for how to get specific value "clickUrl" from file get content web, I'm using file_get_contents function

```html
<?php 
$json_url = "someone.web.id";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},]',"}]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

and the result is

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [serialId] => 110153837
    [productId] => 212065382
    [os] => Linux
    [validResponse] => 1
    [errorMessage] => 
    [adsDetails] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [requestTimestamp] => 1429665317403
                    [adId] => SAP_272131
                    [clickUrl] => http://adtrack.king.com/modules/adTracking/adClicked.jsp?type=ad&st1=startapp&st2=33&st3=us&st4=CCSS_Launchgameplay_PlayNow_480x320_EN&st5=&st6=gmbffR8bQ6WClgZBzdIdIQ&st7=212065382&linkId=3302
                    [trackingClickUrl] => http://www.startappexchange.com/tracking/adClick?d=IAAAAAAgAAA6X15KS0ZCDQlZD0hIFUUDX0BSEUVIVlFLT11EX1tfCAEdQUUFQEVCQk1UQFBRSEhJWFtcUlNPRkdQRUBRQ1NQU1BDSUJCWUxZVgNaS0lSR1dQQE1UX1NDTENMWlhNWlREQUVTQkJUQ0hXTVJARBsdBwhNXVREQ1dQQUkyMSA6W1VCTUFXXlpTRldXQ1dQRkkyMSA6XFRASENFSl5bVjcwMDw%2BJjE5JFNUWF4BEB4TBQpNWlJEQldQS0kCHx1LHwoLGF4aEA4DHg5aQURcFREPFQIMDUBASE0BBwQABBIXUEZTT0VRU0JSU1BcSEdXW1dTIisqJzUtPldSQE0wPUBBSE0mICwmNDE8KyBCQUZcOT4kPjMtOzE6Jyo8SFZOTh4SHRpCQ0hYXE1GV0lXWlZTPyQ7PzE1UUBRTT0ACgoHFFAZCBsbGQwNCldVQUkHERwWC0BGTU1HSltbVlVaR0JcIjksPDMEGkBGTk01PDshSFFBTkNSRlpTSUNXX1NCTklASltXVl1LRUIFFEMFXUEDXwFfTUMVXEJWWVxLXkBRREBQExQBXFIWS1NBWVIvJSErPD0lUUFTTTckIyYtOCI3KCsrSFBKTjMgPzE%2BMzE2OyI%2BWkVAVCstSFBPTkRPQldUR01VQFNRTEhJDF5eX0ZMSkkHExgSFVNTXl5BWkZHVFxNXVBEIDAqUUJXTTgKHRcbFxcRG08nBREcARoABh0OHhEJTi8bFBkADAtNXVJEQ1pQRENWRkZXW1tDS0BBWllWSFJJThcOH1oKGR4CQAATFxQNCh0bGA0KHBAAARUGEVNSX143DxUGEAAADkZOQUkHExgSFVNSXV4XFy8hOkxZX1hMUENZT0BZQFNSV15KSUBXUVlTLywqMjYtNzBCSEVYCAIeChVXUVhTW0tIRUNWREJTRUhUXFNHSkZMSldWVkhIXURCSk1cXUFLXkBLSk0aHAMCSA%3D%3D&lu=http%3A%2F%2Fadtrack.king.com%2Fmodules%2FadTracking%2FadClicked.jsp%3Ftype%3Dad%26st1%3Dstartapp%26st2%3D33%26st3%3Dus%26st4%3DCCSS_Launchgameplay_PlayNow_480x320_EN%26st5%3D%26st6%3DgmbffR8bQ6WClgZBzdIdIQ%26st7%3D212065382%26linkId%3D3302
                    [trackingUrl] => http://www.trackimpression.com/tracking/adImpression?d=IAAAAAAgAAA6X15KS0ZCDQlZD0hIFUUDX0BSEUVIVlFLT11EX1tfCAEdQUUFQEVCQk1UQFBRSEhJWFtcUlNPRkdQRUBRQ1NQU1BDSUJCWUxZVgNaS0lSR1dQQE1UX1NDTENMWlhNWlREQUVTQkJUQ0hXTVJARBsdBwhNXVREQ1dQQUkyMSA6W1VCTUFXXlpTRldXQ1dQRkkyMSA6XFRASENFSl5bVjcwMDw%2BJjE5JFNUWF4BEB4TBQpNWlJEQldQS0kCHx1LHwoLGF4aEA4DHg5aQURcFREPFQIMDUBASE0BBwQABBIXUEZTT0VRU0JSU1BcSEdXW1dTIisqJzUtPldSQE0wPUBBSE0mICwmNDE8KyBCQUZcOT4kPjMtOzE6Jyo8SFZOTh4SHRpCQ0hYXE1GV0lXWlZTPyQ7PzE1UUBRTT0ACgoHFFAZCBsbGQwNCldVQUkHERwWC0BGTU1HSltbVlVaR0JcIjksPDMEGkBGTk01PDshSFFBTkNSRlpTSUNXX1NCTklASltXVl1LRUIFFEMFXUEDXwFfTUMVXEJWWVxLXkBRREBQExQBXFIWS1NBWVIvJSErPD0lUUFTTTckIyYtOCI3KCsrSFBKTjMgPzE%2BMzE2OyI%2BWkVAVCstSFBPTkRPQldUR01VQFNRTEhJDF5eX0ZMSkkHExgSFVNTXl5BWkZHVFxNXVBEIDAqUUJXTTgKHRcbFxcRG08nBREcARoABh0OHhEJTi8bFBkADAtNXVJEQ1pQRENWRkZXW1tDS0BBWllWSFJJThcOH1oKGR4CQAATFxQNCh0bGA0KHBAAARUGEVNSX143DxUGEAAADkZOQUkHExgSFVNSXV4XFy8hOkxZX1hMUENZT0BZQFNSV15KSUBXUVlTLywqMjYtNzBCSEVYCAIeChVXUVhTW0tIRUNWREJTRUhUXFNHSkZMSldWVkhIXURCSk1cXUFLXkBLSk0aHAMCSA%3D%3D
                    [externalTrackingUrl] => 
                    [title] => Candy Crush Soda Saga
                    [description] => Download Candy Crush Soda Saga for free now.Â  Itâ€™s Sodalicious!Candy Crush Soda Saga is a brand new game from the makers of the legendary Candy Crush Saga. New candies, more divine combinations and challenging game modes brimming with purple soda!Candy Crush Soda Saga is completely free to play, ...
                    [imageUrl] => http://lh3.ggpht.com/Igs-DxhnnCi8FfJB4N9LA_rJ0rIYsr553reCLa0Yr3KucEGfUMfzAxu4Co3j-dKrTKI=w100
                    [urlScheme] => 
                      -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How i can get value [clickUrl] ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
foreach($data->adsDetails as $detail) {
   echo $detail->clickUrl;
}
```

Comment: I Glad works for you!, Dont forget to mark as the correct response to help others with the same problem!